# Attaching a mosquito net to a tent

Tags: tents, mosquitoes

Some time ago I bought a [Quechua T4.2 Dome](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jgKx6AZa37Q/maxresdefault.jpg) tent. Lately, when I was on camping holiday with my cousin I saw quite clever solution on their borrowed [Quechua 4.2 Xl Air](http://www.best4tents.com/shoppingcart/product_images/a/t4.2_xl_air__30573.jpg). In such tent, there's always a space between tent's wall and ground to provide ventilation. However, their tent was equipped with mosquito nets all around on the bottom, what provided quite good protection at least against flying bugs.

I was wondering, if it is possible to attach such mosquito nets to mine - for instance, by sewing them to the bottom parts of the tent. I guess, that the biggest risk is that sewing holes might cause tent's walls to start ripping, because it's constantly under tension.

Is it generally a good idea? Or maybe there is a different solution, which will be better in this case? Or should I simply buy another tent? :)

Comment: Your tent was sewn to begin with, you aren't going to tear holes in it by sewing it again. If you're worried about it, then just get some latex fabric glue.

Comment: I've never heard of a tent that came *without* bug netting.

Comment: @ShemSegerit looks like it has bug netting on the two side rooms but has an open middle section that I think he wants to convert. It's still open on the bottom though

Comment: if you look closely, there are already tons of sewing holes in your tent. It is usually a matter of choosing the right seam. In this case, there should little to no tension on the net, so any seam will do.

Comment: @shemSeger, take a closer look on the base of the Air model (look up better photos, maybe). There are nets lying around the tent, attached to its walls. They are not 100%-proof, but screen out some of the flyers. My model lacks them, but they should be quite easy to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many homegrown solutions to this, such as latex glue or even duct tape. If you want to be extra cautious though, approach it like you were patching it. Find the recommended patch kit for that tent, sew the netting to the patches, then attach the patches as if it was a tear. I couldn't find an exact patch kit recommended by Quechua, but you can probably find a variety of colors at any store carrying tents. I would also highly recommend [Gear Aid Tenacious Tape Repair Tape](http://www.rei.com/product/783045/gear-aid-tenacious-tape-repair-tape). It sticks well and comes in a variety of colors or even transparent. Either method would hold up better than duct tape!